# domain connecting to localhost and links not working (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, database-connection, web-hosting

I'm having trouble to get my website properly online, which I created/designed in Wordpress. I have bought a domain and rented a WordPress hosting server. I have uploaded my whole WordPress folder on my server by FileZilla and have as well uploaded my local database over phpMyAdmin to my new database which i got from my hosting provider (Strato). But when ever I'm searching my domain my computer is directly connecting with WordPress on localhost. Which I don't understand why, because I have uploaded my database on the phpMyAdmin account of my host. Shouldn't it then open the domain directly?

When I'm opening a inkognito tab in chrome my website do open, but none of my links are working & an error appears that says **This site can't be reached localhost refused to connect** why does it try to connect with localhost and what can I do that the sites are opening? As well its weird the font on my total website changed by itself, it isn't the one I have chosen and the color have changed also by itself. Does anyone know why this all is happening and what can I do that everything is shown correctly?

PS: in WordPress everything works and looks the way it should but online not!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't migrated the WordPress site to the new domain. WordPress internally stores your domain (http://localhost, because that's what was set when you created the site) and automatically redirects to this URL, as well as prepends it to all permalinks.

To migrate the site, you will have to either

1. use a plugin, like Duplicator ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ )
2. or replace all occurrences of the URL using WP-Client ( https://wp-cli.org/ ) to execute `wp search-replace 'http://localhost' 'https://adrianadesigns.de' inside your WP root directory, then export the database and import in your phpmyadmin

I think the plugin is the simpler solution, refer to the documentation regarding how to use it.